After installing lubuntu i can't access /dev/sda1
It sounds a bit strange, but when I go to the file manager, click "computer" and then the "SATA3 120GB SSD" icon, it says "impossible to mount the file" and "path not mounted".
This is an old Packard Bell dot s SSD. It's a cheap one I found on Amazon, but it worked with Ubuntu (it was too heavy for this PC).
I am on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.
$ lsblk -f

NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL        UUID                                 
FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS

loop0
     squash 4.0                                                           0   100% /snap/bare/5

loop1
     squash 4.0                                                           0   100% /snap/firefox/4793

loop2
     squash 4.0                                                           0   100% /snap/core22/1564

loop3
     squash 4.0                                                           0   100% /snap/firmware-updater/127

loop4
     squash 4.0                                                           0   100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/176

loop5
                                                                          0   100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535

loop6
                                                                          0   100% /snap/snapd/21759

sda                                                                                
└─sda1
     ext4   1.0   lubuntu_2404 ddd56948-e6bf-4bd3-9668-7cf4c4948501   97,3G     6% /

$ df -h

File system     Dim. Usati Dispon. Uso% Montato su
tmpfs           196M  1,5M    195M   1% /run
/dev/sda1       110G  7,0G     97G   7% /
tmpfs           979M  4,0K    979M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  8,0K    5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           979M  4,0K    979M   1% /tmp
tmpfs           196M  2,5M    194M   2% /run/user/1000

I just went through the folders of my PC and found out (thanks to Soren A.'s comment) that the folder /home/palistato is on the SSD and I can use it. So it still confuses me that the file manager says those things, but I don't know if I can still use the space.
So, I don't know, "Solved", I think.

Was the format NTFS? use sudo lsblk -f and [edit] the result in to your question

But isn't /dev/sda1 not already mounted as / ? What is the output of 'df -h' ?
